# OS X IntelliJ IDEA subversion set up

Tags: svn, intellij-idea, osx-yosemite

How do you checkout a Subversion repo on IntelliJ IDEA for OS X?

I am currently trying to checkout a project from a repo hosted on Java.net, but am unable to do so due to the following reasons:

1. There is no prompt for authentication.
2. Checkout status is always in a "In process" stage, and never actually completes (my project is a very small project)

I am very puzzled as to why the checking out process is so tormenting on IDEA. On Netbeans (which sadly, is very laggy on my computer, hence I'm not using it), there are options to input the username and password in the checkout dialog box, and upon submitting, everything is checked out.

However on IntelliJ IDEA, there isn't even a authentication dialog. If anyone has any workaround, please enlighten me. Thank you.

(Sorry if I sound exasperated, because I really am)

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/using-subversion-integration.html

Comment: @Karthikeyan Sorry but I have literally read through everything there, but this "When an authentication challenge comes from the server, the credentials are sought for in the disk cache; if the appropriate credentials are not found, or fail to authenticate, the users is prompted to specify the login name and password." never happens. I've checked my .subversion folder and it's empty. The authentication just never happens!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried this using my IntelliJ 14 on OS X and yup, it doesn't prompt for credentials :-/

If I were you I'd probably save up some nerves and just checkout svn repo using command line, and then import it into the IntelliJ. Luckily, IntelliJ is smart enough to fetch your credentials from local SVN directory (`~/.subversion/auth/` on OS X) so you should be good to go.